# Numerical solution of integral equation involving unknown random variable transformation.

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods, random-variables, integral-equations

Let Y be a random variable normally distributed, and let $X=g(Y)$ be a transformation of Y such that g solves a certain integral equation

$$I[g,F_X]=0$$

where $F_X$ is the distribution function of X.

Solve for g.

The only algorithm I naively came out is:

1. guess an initial probability distribution for X
2. solve I[.,.] for g, given the guessed $F_X$
3. estimate the new $F_X$ given g
4. goto step 2 or exit

Is there a more sophisticated strategy I can adopt for solving this equation? Any reference to articles or books can be helpful.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notation for the "integral equation." What exactly does $I[g,F_X]$ represent?

Comment: $I[g,F_X]$ is an integral expression involving $g$ and $F_X$ in the integral kernel

Comment: $\int$ one of these guys. but no teef.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation The great mathematician ***Erik Ivar Fredholm*** investigated integral equations like these. Maybe they are what you look for?